# Intellij insists on using Android JUnit instead of Gradle for tests

Tags: testing, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module gradle project that includes some core backend modules, as well as different application modules for different platforms.  For example, one android app module, and one module that just runs as a CLI.

I have configured gradle to run tests by going to `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Runner` and both checking the `Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle` checkbox *and* selecting `Gradle Test Runner` from the `Run tests using` dropdown.

I have refreshed Gradle multiple times, as well as invalidating caches / restart.  Despite this, when I click the run icon in the gutter for tests, even in the non-android modules, Intellij creates an Android JUnit configuration to run the test.  This ends up not rebuilding after changes are made.

This did not used to happen, though I'm not sure when it started behaving this way or what changed recently.

How can I force IJ to *always* use gradle?  I'd rather have no Android JUnit available, even in the android module, than the current behavior.

Comment: Please check if Android facet is added to non-android modules: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122904

Comment: Indeed, all modules (except the base) had Android-Gradle under them.  I removed all those entries, but they reappeared after a gradle refresh.

I've looked through the gradle files, and don't see where that could be coming from.  The only occurrences of "android" in my gradle files are:
in settings.gradle, since one module is named 'android'
in the main gradle file, in a line `configure(allprojects - project(':android')) {`
and in the android modules gradle file itself.

So I don't see how this facet is being added to all the other modules.